# Set imageview on an angle, occupying whole width of screen. android:rotation leaves space on both sides

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, imageview, android-imageview

I'm trying to make something like this :

[image]

Went through several answers on stackOverflow and lots of links on google and found nothing but using the attribute "android:rotation" but that is not what I want. Applying Rotation attribute gives me something like this :

[image]

used:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:rotation="5"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />
```

And this is certainly not what I want. Is there any other way ?

Comment: You should think of a solution where you don't rotate the outer `ImageView`, but rather rotate the `Bitmap` itself - maybe by using the `Matrix`?